# Convert Bits to Bytes in Node-Red

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, node-red

I'm new to JavaScript and I use Node-Red to read an write from a Database.

I receive from the database an object that contains the status of 8 digital inputs.
Each inputs is represented as a bit.

I'm looking for a method to combine each bits into a byte.

This is the object that I receive from the database:

```
array[1]
  0: object
    idx: 10
    ts: "2018-11-21T06:12:45.000Z"
    in_0: 1
    in_1: 1
    in_2: 1
    in_3: 1
    in_4: 1
    in_5: 1
    in_6: 1
    in_7: 1
```

in_x represent the input position.

As out I would like to receive a byte that represent the combination of each single byte.

For example:

in0: 0,
in1: 1,
in2: 0,
in3: 0,
in4: 0,
in5: 1,
in6: 0,
in7: 0,

The output byte will be: 00100001 in binary that converted to byte is 33

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will you please explain a bit, what exactly you are expecting in output.

Comment: What have you already tried? Also what representation is the data in LSB, MSB, 2's complement binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works as you requested*:

```
var output = 
    arr[0].in_0 + 
    (arr[0].in_1 << 1) +
    (arr[0].in_2 << 2) +
    (arr[0].in_3 << 3) +
    (arr[0].in_4 << 4) +
    (arr[0].in_5 << 5) +
    (arr[0].in_6 << 6) +
    (arr[0].in_7 << 7);
```

This code assumes that each variable can only be a 1 or a 0. Anything else will result in nonsense.

I have used the [Left Bit Shift operator (<<)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) to obtain the power of two for each on bit.

You have specified that in_7 is the Most Significant Bit. If it is actually the Least Significant Bit, reverse the order of the in_x variables.

*The result is not a byte, but it does contain the number that I think you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but as output I need a byte obtained with Bit Shift. This because the byte will be sent to a Shift Register in order to enable relays.

Comment: Can you provide any more details on the requirements of whatever system you're trying to enter the data into? Perhaps it expects input in a Uint8 Array?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array

Comment: The byte obtained will be sent to a PLC via node-red. So I need an integer.

Comment: My answer does place an integer value in 'output'. Without seeing your code, I don't know what you need to do with it. Possibly all you need is to add: 

msg.payload = output;

Comment: I'm sorry I misinterpreted the answer. It's works! Thank you very much

Comment: Glad to help :)